# EditableGrid Only editing top line

Tags: php, jquery, editablegrid

I am using EditableGrid (http://www.editablegrid.net/)  Which creates some nice looking tables, however every time I try to edit any row other than the first it pulls the first row data into the row.

Here is an example of what is happening:

https://mylinguistica.com/Documentation/editablegrid-mysql-example/

I am using the example code found here:

http://www.editablegrid.net/en/faq

And otherwise everything is working great.  Any Idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but found the solution. My data from the server was using a hardcoded "id" of 1 for every row/record. Once I changed it to increment, everything worked as expected. I suspect since your problem sounds exactly the same that you had the same issue. You've probably figured it out by now but hopefully this answer will help somebody else.

```
{"id":1, "values":{"country":"uk","age":33,"name":"Duke","firstname":"Patience","height":1.842,"email":"patience.duke@gmail.com","lastvisit":"11\/12\/2002"}},
{"id":2, "values":["Rogers","Denise",59,1.627,"us","rogers.d@gmail.com","","07\/05\/2003"]},
```

https://github.com/webismymind/editablegrid/blob/master/examples/json/grid.json